# Not able to require the jqueryui

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I try to require the jquery UI library but If I try to use the functions they are undefined.

here is the code

RequireJS 2.1.11

```
    <script data-main="/js/lpapi/v3/qfapi.js" src="/vendor/requirejs/require.min.js"></script>
```

qfapi.js

```
(function() {
  require.config({
    paths: {
      jquery: '/jquery/jquery-1.11.0.min',
      jqueryui: '/vendor/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min',
      backbone: '/vendor/backbone/backbone-min',
      underscore: '/vendor/underscore/underscore-min'
    },
    shim: {
      "jqueryui": {
        deps: ['jquery'],
        exports: '$'
      },
      "underscore": {
        exports: "_"
      },
      "backbone": {
        exports: 'Backbone',
        deps: ['underscore', "jquery"]
      }
    }
  });

  define(["jquery", "jqueryui", "backbone", "underscore"], function($, _, Backbone) {
    console.log("jquery is loaded");
    console.log("jqueryui is loaded");
    console.log("underscore is loaded");
    console.log("backbone is loaded");
    $("#accordion").accordion();
    return true;
  });

}).call(this);
```

the "accordion" is not a function.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with the code you are showing. Your `define` call should be a `require` call. And your list of arguments is not correct:

```
require(["jquery", "backbone", "underscore", "jqueryui"], function($, _, Backbone) {
```

The way you have it in your question `_` would get an undefined value and `Backbone` would be bound to the `underscore` module.

Your `data-main` should not include the `.js` extension. The value of `data-main` is a module name. RequireJS' module names should generally not contain an extension.